# Blank page issue in Adobe Live Cycle Designer?

Tags: pdf, adobe, livecycle-designer, xfa

There is an Untitled Master Page in our PDF. We can delete it explicitly. But even after deleting it  automatically gets generated again & again. 
Because of this untitled master page we get an unwanted blank page when preview PDF.
we need a way to avoid that blank page

[image]

Comment: You must have a master page. The blank page issue is usually because of your pagination/positioning settings. Can you share, what you have on the pagination palette of your pages and content areas?

Comment: @harun Yea I have attached that on my question by edit that, Problem with Untitled Master Page, It's only visible when i make presence of that following page (see fist image content erase by black ink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check all your content subforms to find out if the pagination/positioning settings are correct. You can check these settings in designer `Object` palette under `Pagination` tab.
Especially look out for the "Place:" property with values of "On Page", "On top of next Page" etc.

[image: Object Palette, Pagination placement setting]

If you have values that don't match to any of your intended master pages, update them, this will allow you to get rid of the untitled master page.

Also check the documentation to understand the meanings of these settings. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/index.htm?content=000512.html